# standard post with extra parameter brings permalink problem

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

This problem concerns several rewrite rules, but i'll stick to one, for clarity.
In my theme, i use a parameter "parentid" which gives me the page/post/custom post i've clicked on (the parent).

**in content.php**
instead of

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

i put

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&parentid=30" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

In this example i arbitrarily set parentid=30, in my code,i would have a value retrieved by get_query_var('p') for instance.

**in functions.php**

```
//I declare the custom query var
function add_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = "parentid"; 
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

and **in header.php**

```
$parentid = get_query_var( 'parentid');
```

So in my case, i have links like

```
?p=12&parentid=30
```

using permaling rewriting, how to add the custom parameter "parentid" ?
I tried

```
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'] = '?p=$matches[1]&parentid=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
```

but "obviously" it doesn't work.
With that rule, the url becomes

```
/wordpress/nom-de-l-article/&parentid=30/
```

instead of

```
/wordpress/nom-de-l-article/30/
```

In fact, in this case, the generic rewrite rule is applied

my rule is ignored because using the plugin [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), my rule, first in the list, has the parameter "p" crossed with the comment : this query variable is not public and will not be saved

My questions :

- what rule should i write, to take into account this custom parameter
  for a "standard" post (?p=xx&parentid=yy)
- Why parentid is not retrieved when the rewrite is active ?  if i echo get_query_var(
  'parentid'); without rewrite i get "30" but with rewrite, i get
  "&parentid=30"  !

Comment: you get back `&parentid=30`, because that's what you're inserting at the end of your URL. if you want just 30, then your URL should be `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>30/"`. also, `p` is supposed to be a post id, if you're passing the slug, you want to use `name=`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. 
for a standard post `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"` gives `?p=whateverid` without rewrite but /nameofpost/ when permalink are activated.
So if i set `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&parentid=30"` i retrieve 30 when i `echo get_query_var( 'parentid')` which is what expected, but this echo gives `&parentid=30` when permlink are rewritten. 
If i do `href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>30`, the permalink will lead to 404 because if will be like `?p=whateverid30`

how would you get the extra parameter?